# How I can make phpunit which test executes now?

Tags: php, phpunit

When I run phpunit unit tests it shows the ouput in a format like:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.............F.................EEEEEEE.......E.................  63 / 271 ( 23%)
.........EFE.............
```

But I want to know what test exactly is running instead of showing the `.` when indicating the current test running. For example a list like:

```
Executing `Tests\App\Mytest.php:test something........[SUCESS] 5s
Executing `Tests\App\Anothertest.php:test something........[FAILED] 5s
```

So how I can change the phpunit's output showing the current test running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with the duration *not* being displayed you can use the `--debug` command-line option to show debug information:

```
phpunit --debug
```

This will return output similar to:

```
PHPUnit 8.4.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Test 'Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::testBasicTest' started
Test 'Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::testBasicTest' ended
Test 'Tests\Feature\PagesTest::usersCanSeeTheWelcomePage' started
Test 'Tests\Feature\PagesTest::usersCanSeeTheWelcomePage' ended

Time: 200 ms, Memory: 24.00 MB
There was 1 failure:
1) Tests\Feature\PagesTest::usersCanSeeTheWelcomePage
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.
[...]
FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 4, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: `--testdox` is pretty useful too. Shows which test is currently running and the status of the previous tests.

Comment: i think as an alternative approach you could use a constructor in each testclass and print the classname and a newline. goes more in the likes of the example OP provided although not as "clean" as the debug flag